# spans within div alignment issue with leftover width

Tags: html, css

im trying to use spans with a div in such a way that the last span occupies the remaining width of the div

```
<div class='data'>
    <span class='one'>dddd:</span>
    <span class='last'>ssss</span>
</div>

.data{width:100%;display:block;} 
span.one{width:30%; border:1px solid red;float: left;}
span.last{width:33%; border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;}
```

So as you can see here

http://jsfiddle.net/gTPjh/3/

its not taking up all the left over space :)

can someone suggest a solution , thnx guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display as a block to fill out space:

```
.data{width:100%;display:block;border:1px solid red; overflow: hidden;} 
span.one{width:30%; border:1px solid red;float: left;}
span.last{ border:1px solid green; display: block; overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: thnx mate this worked as i the above structure in another div element

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a more modern way with css3 `box-sizing: border-box;`([Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gTPjh/29/)).

```
.data{width:100%;display:block;border:1px solid red;} 
span {box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}
span.one{width:30%; border:1px solid red;float: left; }
span.last{width:70%; border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;}
```

That includes the borders while calculating the 30% and 70% width.
But have a look at the current [browser support at caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

To get it to work for example in IE7 it's possible to [simulate the behaviour with css expressions](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2012/08/01/emulate-box-sizing-in-ie7/).
Use it in a IE7 only stylesheet which you can link like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7_fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

use display: table and table-cell as http://jsfiddle.net/gTPjh/33/ shows it works :-) (I love display:table;)

```
.data{ width:100%; display:table; border:1px solid red;} 
span.one{ width:30%; display:table-cell; border:1px solid red;}
span.last{ width:70%; display:table-cell; border:1px solid red;}
```